# Near, near to and nearby. What's the difference?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, adverb-position

Why isn't *near*, *near to* and *nearby* always interchangeable?

They can precede the noun.

- I live **nearby** the railway station
- I live **near** the railway station
- I live **near to** the railway station

When they are *adverbs* they can follow *noun +  be*

- The railway station is **nearby** (my house)
- The railway station is **near** my house
- The railway station is **near to** my house

But we don't normally say:

> ?Meet me at the **near** railway station
>   or
>    ?Meet me at the railway station **near (to)**

The accepted version is:

> Meet me at the railway station **nearby**
>   Meet me at the **nearby** railway station

Why?

Comment: 'Nearby' is not (at least to my knowledge and after a cursory check) used as a preposition, so *_I live nearby the railway station_ is, I'd say, ungrammatical. This usage is seen on the internet; the open compound preposition 'near by' has often been used: _I live near by the railway station_ (cf the old-fashioned _I live close by the railway station_). Similarly, * _The railway station is nearby my house_ is ungrammatical, though the (deictic) adverbial usage _The railway station is nearby_ is fine. 'Near', like 'far', is normally just used (attributively) as a specifying adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, interesting! I would never have thought that usage to be grammatically incorrect. It doesn't sound *wrong* to me though, could my north London roots be responsible?

Comment: 'Near by' doesn't sound very different from 'nearby'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED entry for *near by* | *near-by* | *nearby* happens to classify it as an adjective, an adverb, or a preposition, all depending on its use of course. However, it says that the preposition use means “Close to (a place, etc.). Now *dial.*”  So it has receded to dialectal use. Probably it was in Mari-Lou’s dialect but not in your own.  The OED provides these three citations demonstrating prepositional use: **1456** The citee of Hostrye..is nereby Rome. **1814** Near by the poet’s houseless head. **1889** He lives near by th’ Calvin capil.

Comment: @tchrist None of these is the solid 'nearby' usage (I'm not going back to pre-1500). None is more recent than 1889. I've certainly encountered the MWP ('near by the station') usage, as I indicated above.

Answer (score 5):

> Why isn't *near*, *near to* and *nearby* always interchangeable?
>
> They can precede the noun.  **right**

I follow the latest edition of the *Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*:

1)- *near* as an **adjective**: "*the near[by] shop*"

2)- *near* as an **adverb**: *"he lives near"*, *"the hour is near"*, *"near dead"*

3)- *near* as a **preposition**: *"a house near the river"*

in *some* contexts you can use *near (to)*: "*come near to me!*" "*a house near/close *to the station*". US speakers prefer 'close to', and sometimes 'close to' sounds better anyway: e.g. "The situation is *close to* critical"

4)- 'nearby' is just an adverb. As a preposition it is dialectal, and a spelling variant of  the adjectival phrase *near by* = 'close at hand'.

Those guidelines should solve most of your problems:

> When they are *adverbs* they can  follow the noun. **wrong**
>
> - The railway station is *nearby* [*adverb*]
> - The railway station is *nearby* my house. **wrong**
> - The railway station is *near* my house [*preposition*]
> - The railway station is *near to* my house [*variant*]

probably there is a typo, they **never** follow. If you are referring to *station*, remember that *near* is the predicate.

> But we don't normally say:
>   ?Meet me at the **near** railway station

(this is an **adjective** not an adverb)

> The accepted version is:
>
> Meet me at the railway station **nearby** (*adverb*)
>
> Meet me at the **nearby** railway station (*adjective*)

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nearby?show=0&t=1408541726) also confirms that in the US *nearby* cannot be a preposition, therefore the examples in the other answer should be considered wrong, unless *an explanation is provided*.

> - He ran nearby **a river.**
> - She proceeded nearby **him**

These are prepositions and 'nearby' cannot be used as a preposition; 'alongside', 'near' is appropriate there. Besides this, the fact that the verb is in/transitive is **not** relevant: "she stood near" "she came near". What is fundamental is the distinction between 'adverb' and 'preposition'

For the case of whether "He ran near" is AmEng, I don't know. In terms of whether it is grammatical, I offer:

> 1. near
>
>    - can be used either transitively with a subject, or non-transitively without a subject:
>
>    **transitive**: He ran near me.
>      intransitive: He ran near.

This does not make sense. The verb is intransitive in both cases, in the first case the verb is *intransitive* and 'near' is a *preposition*. It is transitive here: "He ran *a great race*"

Comment: +1 for sheer effort. Thank you, your post has helped me.

Comment: I wouldn't say wrong for nearby as a preposition — the usage may be dialectal, as you note, but if it's dialectal, that means it is correct in some forms of English (which happens to include mine)

Comment: I always write "near by" when it's at the end of a sentence because it seems more obvious that it's adverbial.

Answer (score 4):

I've been considering this for a while, now.  Here's what my thoughts are:

### Near

Near is a good option when you're considering geographical proximity of two stated locations.  If you're literally saying "A is ___ B", it feels most natural to use "near" rather than "near to", "nearby to", or "nearby".

I feel "nearby" is often interchangeable with "near" in this case, but "nearby" does feel a bit more quaint, and it could mean "near and by" (i.e., nearby 3rd street).

### Near to

Should be avoided in the "A is ___ B" pattern for the reason of ambiguity.  "to" can literally mean "until you're right there" (i.e., within touching distance).  So, if you say: "He walked near to the river." You could mean:

Figure (a):

[image: a bloke walking alongside or "near" the river]

(a) He walked near/'mostly alongside' the river.  -or-

---

Figure (b):

[image: a bloke walking near to another bloke to the river]

(b) He walked near to [someone/something, especially the speaker] the river.

---

(a) is intuitive, but a University professor out of the English department might ding you for poor word choice if you form a habit of selecting ambiguous terms.

(b) would be more intuitive if the subject were plural: "*They* walked near to the river."  (b) is apparent with a comma: "He walked near, to the river."  But I've met a lot of opposition from other English instructors; that is, even in case (b), publishers in Japan prefer no comma for High School English.

Different authors have different grammatical styles, which are all equally acceptable.  But this is the somewhat unfortunate model professionals usually go by:

1. Most acceptable: a style people agree with and enjoy.
2. Next-best: a style wherein the reader takes the author's meaning.

### Nearby

When "near" comes at the end of a sentence, it takes on a different meaning.  It may be associated with something abstract: "the end is near."  There may be an omission of an idiomatic object: "I keep her near [to my heart]."

But "nearby" at the end of a sentence means "near" in the "A __ B" sense.  "B" is always the current location.  "The park is near us." = "The park is nearby."

"Nearby" is also the best choice of adjective: "He lives in a nearby house" because "nearby" is so strongly associated with the current location.

I believe "near by" in the "A __ B" means "near and by".  The comma is omitted because it is obvious that they mean the same things.  You could also write "near/by", "near-by", "nearby", or even "near--by".  "He lives near, by the meadow." = "He lives nearby the meadow".  I imagine people use "nearby" because there's no pause required to get the joint meaning across.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer, it's made me think again about my post. I do like your "He walked near to the river" which, if I've understood correctly, you say expresses the concept of person moving towards the river. I suppose it could, but it is also the verb, *walk*/*go* which requires the preposition "to". If a person sets up a tent, would you say: *He set the tent up near or near to the river.*? [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/near-and-near-to) tells me that *near* is more common than *near to* in this case.

Comment: I also think your post should make it clear if any of my examples are ungrammatical as suggested by @EdwinAshworth's [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192319/near-near-to-and-nearby-whats-the-difference#comment401099_192319). I'm trying to get to grips with my *nearby* example being non-standard English, but it's hard! :(

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at their usage tree upside-down.

You are thinking about a predicate and then attempting to discover each usage of *nearness* on that predicate.

To find their differences, you need to invert your box. You don't have to think outside the box, but simply invert the box.

Think about ***near/near to/nearby*** as separate words, each having its own right to its own branch of discovery, to discover what types of predicates each could be applied to.

All three are usable to denote proximity in location. These are the differences.

1. near

   - can be used either transitively with a subject, or non-transitively without a subject:
     transitive: He ran near me.
     intransitive: He ran near.
   - can be used to describe proximity in likeness
     Her intellect is near his.
     The performance of an Intel i3 is nowhere near an Intel i7.
2. near to

   - due to presence of preposition, can only be used transitively.
     He ran near to a river.
   - due to preposition *to*, can be used to indicate vector of nearness.
     He ran near to exhaustion.
     He ate near to a full stomach. (vs He ate near a full stomach)
     She became near to him. (unusable: she became near/nearby him)
     She proceeded near to him = she proceeded towards him, to be near him.
3. nearby

   - can be used either transitively with a subject, or non-transitively without a subject.
     He ran nearby a river.
     He ran nearby.
     She proceeded nearby him = she proceeded towards an unspecified physical, intellectual or conceptual target, while being nearby him.
     The mark on the performance chart of an Intel i5 is nearby that of Intel i7.
   - cannot be used comprehensively to denote proximity in likeness
     unusable: Her intellect is nearby his.
     unusable: The performance of an Intel i3 is nowhere nearby an Intel i7.

I don't think I should rack my brain writing an exhaustive thesis (while my cat is scratching the door to have me let her in for the past half hour), my point is you need to invert your perspective, to define the differences.

Comment: [English-test.net](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic704.html) have (and I agree): The words «nearby» and «near» are very similar in meaning[;] however, there are some differences too. The word «near« can be used as an adjective and as a preposition but «nearby» can be used as an adjective but not as a preposition.

Comment: Is *He ran near.* AmEng? It sounds terribly off. Wouldn't "he ran close by" be more grammatical?

Comment: @Mariloua "He ran near" sounds to my SAE ears as if it were missing something. OTOH nearby works perfectly well as a preposition for me "he ran nearby me". Maybe other AmEng regions will differ, though.